How to fit a 3U in a SysRack?
I have a SysRack 12U cabinet, and a RackChoice 3U. How can I put the 3U inside the 12U cabinet? It doesn't seem to fit. Or are there any other Racks to be used for SysRack?
Cabinet: link on amazon
Rack: link on amazon
The instructions on SysRack don't include how to fit in the actual Racks, so I am confused what to do.
Thanks in advance!

With the door open, the cabinet should have two vertical rails, each with 36 holes, either square or round. You will attach the rack-mount chassis to those rails via the three holes each side of the front panel of the chassis.
If the holes in the rails are square, you may have to get a "rack mount hardware kit" that includes a bunch of square nuts in little spring clips. The clips will fit into the square holes from the back; only install them in the holes where there are holes in the chassis ears. Once they are in place, you can install the chassis using the screws from that same kit.
If the holes are round, they are already threaded. You should have received some rack-mount screws with your chassis, simply thread them through the front panel chassis ears and into the rails. If not, the rack-mount standard is, I believe, 10-32, but you probably don't need to know that; most electronics stores will have rack mount screws available by name.

While I'll be generous and assume that the equipment is designed to be attached only to the front rails, my experience is that most equipment is better served bit both front and rear support. This chassis weighs only 16 lbs but that will increase by the time you put in a PSU and other guts. I would tend to over-engineer specs, both professionally and for personal use.

Fair. But OP did not mention slide rails and I don't see a set of rear rails in that cabinet... though TBH the decoration makes it impossible to see the front rails either.

Usually computer cases are deployed into racks by mounting on horizontal sliding rails.
